# Error:Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation

Tags: apex, integration

I am trying to connect Salesforce with SAP using WSDL code generated to retrieve the data from SAP.

If i give the AccountNo in salesforce it must the fetch the related data from SAP.  Here i have attached the Apex code for calling the end point (Generated WSDL Apex code). I am getting error, i tried a lot but am not able to overcome this.

Kindly any tell how to resolve this.

```
**Error Msg:Error: Compile Error: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation:
sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS: line 19, column 13: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: WebServiceCallout.invoke(sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.zsd_cust_det_webservice, sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZsdCustWebservDemo_element, MAP<String,sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZsdCustWebservDemoResponse_element>, LIST<String>) at line 6 column 72**
```

Code:

```
public class Temperature 
{
String output;
   public void recordReplicator()
   {
   sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.zsd_cust_det_webservice stub=new  sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.zsd_cust_det_webservice();
   String IvAcctNo; 

  output= stub.ZsdTCustDetZsdCustWebservDemo(IvAcctNo);

   }
   public String getOutput()
  {
   return output;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the following:

1. go to Setup > Develop > Apex Classes,
2. click Compile all classes,

and let us know any errors?

Comment: Hi i tried this "compile all classes" getting same error.*Error Msg:Error: Compile Error: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation:
sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS: line 19, column 13: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: WebServiceCallout.invoke(sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.zsd_cust_det_webservice, sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZsdCustWebservDemo_element, MAP<String,sapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZsdCustWebservDemoResponse_element>, LIST<String>) at line 6 column 72**

Comment: Thanks @LavanyaSanathkumar - have you played with the `WebServiceCallout.invoke` signature? How does [this](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_gen_code.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=WebServiceCallout) invocation compare with your generated code?